# How do I perform mathematical operations on all elements of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, permutation

So basically I have a list `[40,1,3,4,20]` and I want to return TRUE if there is a permutation where I can rearrange the numbers in the list mixed with mathematical operations to give a total of 42.
These operators are: (+, -, *). 
An example would be 20 * 4 - 40 + 3 - 1 = 42, therefore it would return `true` for the list `[40,1,3,4,20]`.

For this question I tried using itertool's combination with replacement function to get a list of all possible combinations of operators:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations, combinations_with_replacement
ops = []
perm = permutations([40,1,3,4,20], 5)
comb = combinations_with_replacement(["+","-","*"], 5)
for i in list(comb):
    ops.append(i)

print(ops)
```

this gives me:

```
[('+', '+', '+', '+', '+'),
 ('+', '+', '+', '+', '-'),
 ('+', '+', '+', '+', '*'),
 ('+', '+', '+', '-', '-'),
 ('+', '+', '+', '-', '*'),
 ('+', '+', '+', '*', '*'),
 ('+', '+', '-', '-', '-'),
 ('+', '+', '-', '-', '*'),
 ('+', '+', '-', '*', '*'),
 ('+', '+', '*', '*', '*'),
 ('+', '-', '-', '-', '-'),
 ('+', '-', '-', '-', '*'),
 ('+', '-', '-', '*', '*'),
 ('+', '-', '*', '*', '*'),
 ('+', '*', '*', '*', '*'),
 ('-', '-', '-', '-', '-'),
 ('-', '-', '-', '-', '*'),
 ('-', '-', '-', '*', '*'),
 ('-', '-', '*', '*', '*'),
 ('-', '*', '*', '*', '*'),
 ('*', '*', '*', '*', '*')]
```

How would I apply these 21 unique combinations of mathematical operations and iterate it over the elements in my list? I have tried a couple of things but everything gets a bit hairy and confusing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To avoid looking for the operator from symbol, I'd suggest to directly use the operators
- then the operator sublist, should be one element smaller than the value sublists, 5 values need 4 operators
- to get all the possibilities, use `product` for the operators

For each sublist of value, for each sublist of operator : compute the result

- apply the operator on the previous value and the current one
- you can now check if is equals your goal value
- it it matches, some formatting, and you're done with an expression

```
from itertools import permutations, product, chain, zip_longest
from operator import add, sub, mul

def operator_to_symbol(ope):
    return {add: "+", sub: "-", mul: "*"}.get(ope, "")

def format_result(values, ops):
    return " ".join(list(chain(*zip_longest(values, ops)))[:-1])

def evaluate(values, operators):
    v = values[0]
    for idx, val in enumerate(values[1:]):
        v = operators[idx](v, val)
    return v


if __name__ == "__main__":
    perm_values = list(permutations([40, 1, 3, 4, 20], 5))
    comb_operator = list(product([add, sub, mul], repeat=4))

    goal = 42
    for p in perm_values:
        for c in comb_operator:
            v = evaluate(p, c)
            if v == 42:
                print(format_result(map(str, p), list(map(operator_to_symbol, c))), "=", goal)
```

Gives only one unique result :

```
4 * 20 - 40 - 1 + 3 = 42
4 * 20 - 40 + 3 - 1 = 42
4 * 20 - 1 - 40 + 3 = 42
4 * 20 - 1 + 3 - 40 = 42
4 * 20 + 3 - 40 - 1 = 42
4 * 20 + 3 - 1 - 40 = 42
20 * 4 - 40 - 1 + 3 = 42
20 * 4 - 40 + 3 - 1 = 42
20 * 4 - 1 - 40 + 3 = 42
20 * 4 - 1 + 3 - 40 = 42
20 * 4 + 3 - 40 - 1 = 42
20 * 4 + 3 - 1 - 40 = 42
```